# How to output the following equation?

Tags: equations

What is the code to produce the following?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Load `amsmath` and `amssymb` packages.

On preamble:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\med}{med}
```

Then:

```
\[ \operatorname{MC}(F) = \med_{x_1 \leqslant m_F \leqslant x_2} h(x_1,x_2) \]
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\med}{med}

\begin{document}

\[ \operatorname{MC}(F) = \med_{x_1\leqslant m_F \leqslant x_2} h(x_1,x_2) \]

\end{document}
```

**ps.** note that the font is not the same. I used the default one.